# Outlook email: Hide empty tag with CSS

Tags: css, email, outlook, css-selectors

I have tried using pseudo-selector to hide empty tags in the email, it works on Outlook for Mac but not in Outlook 15.xx.xx(2013) in windows.
I realize after checking https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ that pseudo-selectors are not supported fully.

HTML:

```css
ul li:empty { 
   display: none; 
   mso-hide:all; 
   font-size: 0;
   max-height: 0; 
   line-height: 0;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>::ROLE_1</li>
  <li>::ROLE_2</li>
  <li>::ROLE_3</li>
  <li>::ROLE_4</li>
</ul>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the example each `<li>` has text therefore not `:empty`. `:empty` elements must not have any content (ie no elements or text).

Comment: Keep email simple -- why would you have an empty `<li>` in the HTML in the first place? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: @zer00ne The Roles in the <li> specified are dynamic variables. so when it renders not all 4 roles would be rendered.

Comment: @zer00ne makes a really good point. Why are you serving empty list items in the first place. You should be using server side/platform logic to determine what shows and what doesn't.

Comment: Completely agree, we are using legacy sendGrid templates, it does not support handlebars. We are trying to move to dynamic templates, will keep you guys posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution, removed styles and moved the logic to server side/backend to pass ASCII DOT value ( to mimic unordered list) along with dynamic role.